# Change version file automatically on commit with git

Tags: git, github, version, bitbucket

We have our master branch that we merge our features into. I need to be able to increment our version on commit/merge to the master automatically as a part of the merge. Is there a way i can do this so that the upped version is committed as a part of this commit without having to have an automatic 're checkout, change, commit' that will effectively double all our commits?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can use [git hooks](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks) for that.

The `pre-commit` hook specifically. You can create one from the sample in `.git/hooks/pre-commit.sample` by removing the `.sample` suffix and editing it. The content of `pre-commit` will be executed just before the commit.

It could contain something like this

```
#!/bin/sh
command-that-increases-version version.text
git add version.text
```

Any modification of `version.text` will then be included in the commit.

Finally some advice: you may want to avoid doing this altogether, since it may lead to a lot of merge conflicts when different branches store different values in `version.text`.

Answer (score 2):

### 1. main.py

```sh
version = open("VERSION.TXT", "r").read()
```

### 2. root dir repository

```sh
echo 1 > VERSION.TXT
```

## 3. add git hook

```sh
# cat .git/hooks/post-commit
#/bin/sh
echo "post-commit started"  
version=$(cat VERSION.TXT); y=$((version=version+1)); echo $y > VERSION.TXT
```

## 4. done

```sh
git commit .
git push
```