# Identify on which branch a commit occurred

Tags: git, bash

I am using a git repository and I wanted to create a script that would increment the version number of my application by knowing on which branch a commit occur. There are three branches "hotfix" "feature" and "release" and based on which branch a commit occurs I wanted to increment the version number.

For example if i have an application called xyz.1.0.0 and if a commit occurred on "hotfix" increment the last number like xyz.1.0.1 or if a commit occurred on "feature" increment the middle number like xyz.1.1.0 and so on.

Comment: After merging and/or deleting branches you cannot tell what branch it was committed to. Belonging to a branch is resolved in run time.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. The question as it stands is likely to be closed because it doesn't include your current code - SO is not a programming service, but rather somewhere to ask about specific issues with existing code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find out which branch you currently have checked out with `git symbolic-ref --short HEAD`.  You can then use a [commit hook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17101473/change-version-file-automatically-on-commit-with-git) to increment your version number as you like.

Because of the nature of Git branches, they are just labels, there is no way to definitively tell what branch the user was on after a commit was made.  It is even possible to commit work in Git without being on a named branch (the "detached HEAD" state).