# Auto increment version number in a Python webserver, with git

Tags: python, git, git-commit

I have a Python webserver (using Bottle or Flask or any other) that I develop locally:

```
BUILDVERSION = "0.0.128"

@route('/')
def homepage():    
    ... # using a template, and the homepage shows the BUILDVERSION in the footer
        # so that I always know which live version is running

...

run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8080)
```

Each time I have a significant update, I do:

```
git commit -am "Commit name" && git push
```

and the distant version is updated. (Note: I use `git config receive.denyCurrentBranch updateInstead` on the distant repo).

Problem: I often forget to manually increment the `BUILDVERSION` on each commit, and then it's not easy to distinguish which version is running live, etc. (because two consecutive commits could have the same `BUILDVERSION`!)

**Question: Is there a way to have an auto-incrementing `BUILDVERSION` on each commit with Python + Git?** or anything similar (the BUILDVERSION could also be the commit ID...) that would be present in small characters in the footer of the website, allowing to distinguish consecutive versions of the Python code.

Comment: If you run this command inside your repo `git log | head -1 | awk '{print $2}'` do you get the `commit id`?

Comment: @Hackerman on destination, yes (Linux), it works. On source, no (Windows ;)).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change version file automatically on commit with git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17101473/change-version-file-automatically-on-commit-with-git)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As mentioned in [Change version file automatically on commit with git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17101473/change-version-file-automatically-on-commit-with-git), 
git [hooks](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks) and more specifically a `pre-commit` hook can be used to do that.

In the specific case of Python, [versioneer](https://github.com/warner/python-versioneer) or [bumpversion](https://github.com/peritus/bumpversion) can be used inside the `.git/hooks/pre-commit`  script:

```
#!/bin/sh
bumpversion minor
git add versionfile
```

---

Another option is to use the git commit id instead of a `BUILDVERSION`:

```
import git
COMMITID = git.Repo().head.object.hexsha[:7]    # 270ac70
```

(This requires `pip install gitpython` first)

Then it's possible to compare it with the current commit ID with `git log` or `git rev-parse --short HEAD` (7 digits is the Git default for a short SHA).